# Bootstrap text and image

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap and I have a row that contains 2 divs. The first div contains an image and the second div contains the text.

I want the text to come up to the edge of the image, but the image doesn't fill the entire div. If I make the div smaller, the image is scaled and causes the same problem.

Both divs are col-xl-6 but the image is centered leaving a gap around the sides, and therefore a space between the end of the image and the start of the text.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-md-7 offset-md-1 col-sm-9 col-8">
                <div class="carousel-item active mt-4"><img src="{{ project.image.url}}" alt="img" class="img-thumbnail mx-auto d-block"></div>
            </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="mt-4 mb-4">
<label class="main-content-label my-auto pt-2 tx-15-f">{{project.name}}</label>
            <h6 class="mt-4 fs-16">Description</h6>
            <p>{{project.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this makes sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inner columns from each column, too many columns inside columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="carousel-item active mt-4"><img src="{{ project.image.url}}" alt="img" class="img-thumbnail mx-auto d-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
        <label class="main-content-label my-auto pt-2 tx-15-f">{{project.name}}</label>
        <h6 class="mt-4 fs-16">Description</h6>
        <p>{{project.description}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```